# Scan arguments and determine what they are with a c++ program

Tags: c++, input

This is a homework assignment first off.

We have to create a "common application-programming model in UNIX/Linux known as the filter".

I'm stuck on reading the input passed through as arguments (it's all I ever seem to have trouble on).

For example, the *cmd* is open and the following line is entered:

```
program -isomebinaryfile.bin
```

I need to determine what the first letter is after the hyphen (`-`) and so on and so forth.

Is `scanf` what I would be using? My `main` is set up to be able to accept arguments:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
FILE *inf = NULL;
char *arg = argv[0];
}
```

Can someone give me a little help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your assignment is only to handle processing of arguments, you may want to look up `getopt` - it's a standard library parser for arguments.

As for the meat of your question, there are a lot of options, and you could use `sscanf` as part of it, but you don't have to.

To parse the one argument you mentioned, you need to do the following:  check if the argument begins with -i, grab the data out of the argument.

The easiest way to check if the argument begins with -i is:

```
if (argv[1][0] == '-' && argv[1][1] == 'i')
```

Alternatively, if you have a lot of argument options, all beginning with '-', you may want something like:

```
char * i = NULL;
char * o = NULL;
char * s = NULL;
for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
    if (argv[i][0] == '-') {
        switch(argv[i][1]) {
            case 'i':
                i = argv[i][2];
                break;
            case 's':
                s = argv[i][2];
                break;
            case 'o':
                o = argv[i][2];
                break;
            default:
                cerr << "Unknown option: " << argv[i][1];
        }
     } else {
        cerr << "Error: all options must begin with '-'";
     }
```

Note, I'm using argv[**1**], not 0.  argv[0] is always the name of the executable.

The fastest way to extract the rest of the argument is simple pointer arithmetic:

```
char * filename = argv[1] + 2;  // (Or you could equivalently say = &argv[1][2]
```

This is most efficient - it reuses the strings that are already in argv.  If you're planning on changing the strings around, you'd do better with strcpy:

```
char * filename = (char *)malloc(strlen(argv[1]) - 2);
strcpy(filename, argv1 + 2);
// and eventually you'd have to free(filename)...
```

Play around and experiment with all the string functions.  You'll find them essential to all of your later programs.

Comment: very descriptive, thanks a lot for the help. Learned lots here.

Comment: although, I ran into a problem. I can input multiple arguements in one line. for exmaple:

-isomebinaryfile.bin -oOutputfilename -srec

Comment: check the "Alternatively, if you have a lot of argument options" section.  Hopefully, it should be obvious to you how to extend from there if you have further options.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [getopt](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt). The manual page has an example.

Answer (score 1):

`argv` is an array of strings.  You can loop over them like

```
for (int i=1; i<argc; i++) { // skip argv[0] as that's this program's name
    const char* arg = argv[i];
}
```

Once you have the string for a particular argument, you can use the string manipulation functions from `<string.h>`

```
if (arg[0] == '-' && strlen(arg) > 0) {
    arg++; // advance past the leading '-'
    if (strcmp(arg, "command_one") == 0) {
        // handle command_one
    }
    else if (strcmp(arg, "command_one") == 0) {
        ....
    else {
        printf("Error: unexpected command %s\n", arg);
    }
```

Comment: `argv[0]` is the name of the executable

Comment: @EdHeal Yes.  I didn't mean to suggest otherwise. I'll try to fix my answer if you can confirm what seemed misleading. Was it starting the first loop from 0 rather than 1?

Comment: I would prefer a `while` loop over a `for` loop for this, since you may want to irregularly move through the arguments depending on how many parameters a command-line setting takes.

Comment: This is excellent. Althought, one thing. When compairing for the hyphen (-) it won't compair on it's on becaise it would be part of the bigger word. For example, 

-isomebinaryfile.bin 

That's one argument, meaning '-' cannot be on it's own. Is there a way I could go through each character in the argument to compair?

Comment: @Robolisk You can use `strcmp` on the full argument or use a `for` loop accessing single characters using `arg[i]` for values of `0<=i<strlen(arg)`

Answer (score 0):

Get arguments from `argv` ("argument vector").  In your example, `argc` and `argv` will be as follows:

```
argc == 2
argv[0] == "cmd"
argv[1] == "-isomebinaryfile.bin"
```

Finding the first letter after the hyphen in `argv[1]` is a simple loop.